# Stability of 4-pyridone vs 4-pyridinol

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, isomers, tautomer

In kryptomerism assignment, there was a question to compare more stable tautomeric form between 4-pyridone (**1**) and 4-pyridinol (**2**):

[image: 1: 4-pyridone; 2: 4-pyridinol]

**Answer**: 4-pyridone.

My friend gave two plausible reasons:

1. $\ce{C=O}$ is more stable than $\ce{C=N}.$
2. $\ce{-N=}$ will have greater repulsion between the lone-pair and the double bond than the same in $\ce{-O=}.$

Though, not being convinced by his explanation, I have two questions. First, is the answer correct? And second, what's the reason if it's correct?

Comment: In my opinion, the aromaticity gained by 4-pyridinol would offset the energy considerations mentioned by @Zenix's friend, making it more stable.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb both are aromatic

Comment: @Zenix researched and answered accordingly. You're pretty sharp for someone in eighth grade :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is an either this or that situation. As with most of the equilibria we know it depends very much on the circumstances we look at it. Many examples of keto-enol-tautomerism are heavily influenced by the solvent. Due to time and resource restrictions I won't be able to go in as much detail as I did in *[explaining whether enolates get protonated at the carbon or oxygen atom](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37224/4945)*, but I ran a few calculations showing some of the controversy.

The calculations were carried out using Gaussian 16 Rev. B.01 at the DF-B97D3(BJ)/def2-TZVPP level of theory, and thermal corrections were obtained from normal coordinate analysis (in the harmonic approximation) at the optimised structures at the same level of theory using $T=\pu{273.15 K}$ and $p=\pu{1 atm}$ (because that is the G16 standard, sorry for the non-SI). The polarisable continuum model was employed except for the gas phase. All energies are in $\pu{kJ mol^-1}$ for reaction \eqref{tauto}, which means that negative values indicate that 4-pyridinol is more stable than 4-pyridone and vice versa for positive values:<sup>*</sup>
$$\ce{4-pyridinol <=> 4-pyridone}\tag1\label{tauto}$$

\begin{array}{lrrr}
\text{solvent} & \Delta E_\mathrm{el} & \Delta E_\mathrm{o} & \Delta G \\
\hline
\text{gas}     &  -3.4  &  -4.2  &  -3.7  \\
\text{water}   &  21.0  &  18.7  &  18.9  \\
\text{benzene} &   6.9  &   5.2  &   5.5  \\
\hline
\end{array}

From this we can imply (although there are too few points) that in condensed phase 4-pyridone is the predominant species, while in vacuum it would be 4-pyridinol. Unfortunately, at this time I cannot offer a satisfactory (and easy) explanation for this. The values above have not been calibrated, they are a mere snapshot. I don't want to wander deep into hand-wavy territory and propose a rule of thumb based on bond energies and/or similarities to other molecules.

It is probably true that water is able to stabilise a possible negative charge at the oxygen and at the same time stabilising the positive charge of the proton bonded to nitrogen, but that's about as much of an educated guess I would like to give up.

I want to caution everybody with expressions like *the aromatic form* when referring to a resonance contributor. Aromaticity is a concept which applies to a (sub-) structure and as such to all resonance contributors. This is why both tautomers are aromatic regardless of the depiction chosen.
In a similar way I want to caution against the argumentation with bond energies. Whenever resonance comes into play, we will have fractional bond orders, which deviate significantly from the conditions under which the tabulated values have been measured (or calculated).

The above notes apply directly to the two reasons your friend offers:

> My friend gave two plausible reasons:
>
> 1. $\ce{C=O}$ is more stable than $\ce{C=N}.$
> 2. $\ce{-N=}$ will have greater repulsion between the lone-pair and the double bond than the same in $\ce{-O=}.$

There is neither an isolated $\ce{C=O}$, nor a $\ce{C=N}$ bond, as they are both part of the same π-system. The lone pairs cannot (directly) interfere with the π-system as they are orthogonal.

I wish I could offer you a better explanation, but with most chemistry there is nothing easy about simple systems.

---

*Notes:*

- There is a more extensive theoretical study available, which compares THF, water, and methanol and focuses more on the solvent model. However, obtained values are in a similar region:

  Nagy, P. I.; Alagona, G.; Ghio, C. Theoretical Investigation of Tautomeric Equilibria for Isonicotinic Acid, 4-Pyridone, and Acetylacetone in Vacuo and in Solution. *J. Chem. Theory Comput.* **2007,** *3* (4), 1249–1266. [DOI: 10.1021/ct6002252](https://doi.org/10.1021/ct6002252).
- <sup>*</sup> For those unfamiliar with the notations: $\Delta E_\mathrm{el}$ refers to the electronic energy in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation; $\Delta E_\mathrm{o}$ refers to the observed energy, i.e. it is the former including the zero-point energy correction; $\Delta G$ refers to the Gibbs energy.

Comment: When I have more time, I might come back to this and add some more calculations. And if I find a nice way to look at the solutions and analyse them I will add that, too.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and cautioning me not to jump into hasty conclusion. Do you have access to ACS papers mentioned by HahaHaha in his answer.

Comment: @Zenix I wasn't really correcting you, merely pointing out a different view. And after all you have had some doubts about your approach that needed clearing up. It's a good instinct to question things as they don't always are as easy as it seems, or less so: obvious. I currently do not have access to the publication mentioned by Haha; I have my doubts about how comparable this molecule is with the ones we're looking at.

Comment: Ik that two compounds aren't same that I am particularly interested in, but reason provided there for stability might be of some help. Further it isn't *that important*, so don't purchase the membership of ACS for this answer.....

Comment: The solvent dependence is pretty interesting. Do you have dipole moments of the two molecules? Joule/Mills, *Heterocyclic Chemistry* 5th ed. agrees with your findings (pp 141–2): "Under all normal conditions, [2- and 4-hydroxypyridine] exist almost entirely in the carbonyl tautomeric form [...] the hydroxy-tautomers are detected in significant amounts only in very dilute solutions in non-polar solvents [...] or in the gas phase. The polarised pyridone form is favoured by solvation."

Comment: & the references it cites: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00417a027, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4020(01)83237-3, https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01296a002, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(01)86850-7. Feel free to use all, any, or none; I'm too lazy to read them properly.

Comment: @orthocresol The calculated dipole moments for pyridone in the order gas, water, benzene: 6.7502; 9.6483; 7.9517. And for pyridinol (same): 2.7196; 3.7804; 3.1573. I probably have neither access, nor time, nor the patience to go through the material, but I might add it as a note, if (or when) I come back to this post. Thanks for digging anyway.

Comment: If I find the time I might write an answer based on the polarity / solvation link, but that can only rationalise the trend going from gas-phase -> benzene -> water... it is certainly not trivial, perhaps impossible, to explain why gas-phase pyridinol is more stable than pyridone to begin with.

Comment: Okay i gotta give this one totally to you, great answer, i learnt a lot from it. The answer could be in the grey zone is what i failed to understand. Thanks for the inputs to my answer and the great answer, and my apologies for getting too excited with my answer @Martin-マーチン i guess being anew user i got too excited by the data evidences i was getting for what is the answer.

Comment: *In a similar way I want to caution against the argumentation with bond energies. Whenever resonance comes into play, we will have fractional bond orders, which deviate significantly from the conditions under which the tabulated values have been measured (or calculated).* I was just curious if this is correct: if I add all the bond energies not considering the delocalisation, and then subtract the resonance energy, then I will get the resultant bond energy. (Of course, my answer will not hold, as I do not even know the resonance energies), but is what I said right now correct @Martin-マーチン?

Comment: @Zenix the bounty ends in 4 hrs, imo you should accept martin’s answer

Comment: @HahaHahaha I guess accepting answer won't give Martin bounty, further reasons that I was looking for aren't given in this answer. Answer seems even more mystified after this. It's in the hand of Andselisk to award bounty, not in my hand... I will accept the answer as soon as all my queries are answered.

Comment: Idk to whom @andselisk will award bounty...

Comment: @HahaHahaha That approach might be valid, if you actually know these values as independent data points. It could well be that you are running in some kind of circular reasoning, or self-fulfilling prophecy, for the cases where the one is derived from the other. I generally only wanted to caution, not say a rigorous no to the approach; models have limitations, even the one I have used. If you know them well enough, you can apply the models, otherwise you might get a false positive (or explanation).

Comment: @Zenix The answers you are looking for probably does not exist; at least there won't be a simple explanation, which you can summarise in two keywords. I agree with orthocresol that any explanation of the solvation-stability relation won't be trivial; I share the fear that it might be impossible to explain the gas phase at all. I don't know whether there is enough experimental data to correlate the findings to (I believe I read somewhere that they decompose before being able to measure them in the gas phase). I hope you won't be too disappointed

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: Pls see [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/146400/why-is-quinone-mono-oxime-more-stable-than-para-nitrosophenol_) also.

Answer (score 1):

[This Article](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1973/P2/p29730001080#!divAbstract) states the following about 4-pyridone in its abstract:

> Aromatic resonance energies for 4-pyridone and its analogues are similar to those for the 2-pyridone series.

This means that in order to find out how 4-pyridone is so stable, all we have to do is take a look at it's sister, 2-pyridone. 2-pyridone and it's tautomeric form, 2-pyridinol have the following resonance structures respectively, as shown in [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55075/why-is-the-thione-tautomeric-form-of-2-mercaptopyridine-favoured) question.

[image: Resonance of 2-pyridinol] [image: Resonance of 2-pyridinone]

The major reason of the stability of 2-pyridone is that **Its aromatic form has the negative charge on the more electronegative element and the positive charge on the more electropositive element**. More about the tautomerism of 2-pyridone can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Pyridone#Tautomerism), however for the purposes of this explanation I'll restrict myself to the above concept.

Applying this concept to the resonance of 4-pyridone and 4-pyridinol respectively, we obtain the following structures:

[image: Resonance of 4-pyridinol]

[image: Resonance of 4-pyridinone]

This explains why 4-pyridone is more stable than 4-pyridinol

**References:**

- *Cook, Michael J.*; *Katritzky, Alan R.*; *Linda, Paolo*; *Tack, Robert D.*: Aromaticity and tautomerism. Part II. The 4-pyridone, 2-quinolone, and 1-isoquinolone series. J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. 2, 1973, 1080-1086
- *Forlani L.; Cristoni G.; Boga C.; Todesco P. E.; Del Vecchio E.; Selva S.; Monari M.* (2002). Reinvestigation of tautomerism of some substituted 2-hydroxypyridines. Arkivoc. XI: 198–215.

Comment: I have a doubt, isn't in the question asked [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/55075/50406),OP make fundamental mistakes in counting no. of π electrons. Also your answer is contrary to what answer says, and acc. to you 2-pyridinol is more stable, which is not the case

Comment: Sorry I fixed a couple typos above. As for the answer, the $\ce{\pi}$ electrons seem in order. Nitrogen’s orbitals in 4-pyridinone are sp3 hybridised and the lone pair electrons in the sp2 orbital do not contribute to aromaticity

Comment: "On the 2-pyridone resonance forms (right) we have on the left side of the equilibrium a non aromatic (8pi e−) uncharged molecule and on the right side an aromatic (6pi e−) charged molecule", this is quoted from above link. How are there 8π e- and aren't both aromatic?

Comment: Both are **not** aromatic. The nitrogen having two lone pairs does not conjugate it's lone pairs with the pi-electron system in the resonance structure as it's orbitals are sp3 hybridized.

Comment: There are **no** sp3 nitrogens in any of these structures. Mind you, it's not possible for hybridisation to change between two different resonance forms of the same thing.

Comment: @orthocresol aren't both aromatic? Also can you please check my first comment on this answer and verify or correct me...

Comment: The bottom image uses the wrong arrows, these symbolise tautomerism, but the correct form would be $\ce{<->}$ for resonance (or mesomerism [outdated]).

Answer (score 0):

This answer does seem right. In the reaction I have drawn here, a similar logic prevails, you would be shocked to know that the equilibrium shifts to the right here in an ethanolic solution. The reason simply is the very high $\ce{C=O}$ bond energy. $\ce{C=O}$ has a bond energy of more than $\pu{100 kJ/mol}$ than the $\ce{C=N}$ and $\ce{C=C}$ bond energies (data from [here](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/cyerkes/Chem104ACSpring2009/Genchemref/bondenergies.html)). So, both these compound being aromatic, the debate of resonance energy dies, so it is a perfect explanation.

Here is a solid ACS paper<sup>[1]</sup> which says the same, the source for my claim even if you cannot access the paid version if you are not an ACS member, the first page is free, you can read clearly, that the mixture exists largely in the **quinoid** form.

On page 72 in the paper by Suzanne Slayden and Joel Liebmann titled *The organic thermochemistry of hydroxylamines oximes hydroxamic acids and their derivatives*, there is proof as well as **justification of the same**.

[image: tautomerisation of quinone oximes and nitrosoarenols[*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1934,** *56* (3), 732–735](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01318a062)]

#### References:

1. Anderson, L. C.; Yanke, R. L. The Tautomerism of Quinoneoxime-para-nitrosophenol Systems1. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1934,** *56* (3), 732–735. [DOI: 10.1021/ja01318a062](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01318a062).
2. Rappoport, Z.; Liebman, J. F. (eds.): The Chemistry of Hydroxylamines, Oximes and Hydroxamic Acids, Volume 1. John Wiley & Sons, 2008. (See a preview on [books.google.co.in](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XKP-mFbCs_0C&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=4-nitrosophenol%20tautomerism&source=bl&ots=beyv9-avXR&sig=ACfU3U1Ybd2A_LMBIN-Ba6IGlOlB6l3LsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv_dynxObmAhVzxzgGHbDrCE44ChDoATARegQICRAB#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

Comment: I am sorry for the weird screenshot, I'm a new user and not aware how you guys draw reactions

Comment: ChemDoodle is fine, but it would be nice to crop the image so that it's not bloated with the irrelevant web interface elements. Also, there is a brief [software community Wiki](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880). If you are interested in tips on formatting, feel free to visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: One more thing: cite the *original source* whenever possible. [The web page](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/cyerkes/Chem104ACSpring2009/Genchemref/bondenergies.html) states the data is "*Referenced from Chemistry by Zumdahl (5th ed.) Table 8.4 on page 373*", so it's a good idea to cite the textbook as a primary source and append URL for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the help andselik, but what should I cite when the reaction was given by my teacher in-class notes? Is citation avoidable in such situations, because i do not have many books at my disposal to search from where the reaction was given. Thanks for the software I will try.

Comment: Regarding citing the reaction by your teacher: it's a gray zone. Most likely, the teacher adapted it from somewhere else, so ideally that original source should be cited. If finding this out is deemed impossible, then post it as is (e.g. citing your teacher's private lecture notes), but be prepared for the critique for the lack of credibility of such source.

Comment: As said by @andselisk, here comes your first critique. Your answer seems correct. And have a look what explanation my friend gave.... But bounty was placed to cite the source...

Comment: found it @Zenix I guess ACS is trustworthy enough

Comment: Thanks for the research, so the answer given is correct. But I am afraid if first page provide reason for the same? No, I do not have the paid membership of ACS. In case you have, what's the reason that this article provide, and on which page..

Comment: Nah, nor do I, I'm pretty much a starter in organic chemistry. Ill try and find something else

Comment: I searched a lot, all I could find is NMR proof on the first page of the acs link I showed you which says the answer is correct. Why is c=o bond energy not acceptable??/

Comment: Please do not use edit statements, rewrite your post as necessary to form a continuous text. New readers will not care about the timely progression of writing; for those interested there is the history available. I have cleaned up your post a bit also using the mhchem package (look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Also note that not all content on google books is licensed everywhere; it would be better to quote the relevant portions and leave a link as reference.

Comment: For the chemistry at hand: I do think that the molecules you cite a fundamentally different from what was asked in the question, and I would not be too sure to make this leap in argument.

Comment: For the re edits, sorry i wont do that again, as for the the chemistry, nature loves the $C=O$ bond over aromatic hetero rings of nitrogen, as this is illustated in my example, the question itself, in the struture of guanine, in the structure of cytosine, in the structure of thyaime, in the structure of uracil, etc. So i do not agree with you that the chemistry in different. In my opionion its a perfect analogy. If there was exact data easily available, then Zenix wouldnt ask this and Andselisk wouldnt bounty it. @Martin-マーチン

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the dominance form of the compound depends on which phase it is in. Ref.1 states that:

> In the gas phase, there is a preference of the hydroxy form in both 2- and 4-hydroxypyridine, while in a nonpolar solvents such as cyclohexane and chloroform, the two tautomers exist in comparable amounts. However, the two equilibria are shifted entirely to the right in favor of the *oxo*-form, 2- and 4-pyridone, respectively in polar solvents as well as in the crystalline state.

In general, pyridones (e.g., 4-pyridone) predominance strongly over their tautomeric hydroxy forms (e.g., 4-hydroxypyridine) can be rationalized by considering the mesomerism of the alternative forms. The charge-separated form of 4-pyridone (far left; negative charge on more negative oxygen), being aromatic, is greatly preferred over the nonaromatic, charge-separated form of 4-hydroxypyridine (far right; negative charge on relatively more positive nitrogen).

[image: Pyridone-hydroxypyridine]

There are compilations about this type of keto-enol tautomerism.   The freely available [Tautobase](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035) for example is provided as searchable database in [DataWarrior](http://openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html).

**References:**

1. Jiali Gao, Lei Shao, "Polarization Effects on the Tautomeric Equilibria of 2- and 4-Hydroxypyridine in Aqueous and Organic Solution," *J. Phys. Chem.* **1994**, *98(51)*, 13772–13779 (https://doi.org/10.1021/j100102a051).
2. Oya Wahl, Thomas Sander, "Tautobase: An Open Tautomer Database", *Chem. Inf. Model.* **2020**, *60*, 1085–1089 ([doi 10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035)).

Comment: @Buttonwood: Thanks for addition of good reference.