# Phenol vs 4-hydroxypyridine - Enol Content

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

[image]

> Which has a higher enol content; phenol or 4-hydroxypyridine?

The solution to this question in my book says that phenol has a higher enol content due to aromaticity. But 4-hydroxypyridine is also stabilized by resonance. So how does that affect enol content?

Comment: Aromaticity in the keto form, if present, does matters too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stability of 4-pyridone vs 4-pyridinol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125617/stability-of-4-pyridone-vs-4-pyridinol)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution manual correctly predict that phenol has a higher enol content due to aromaticity. For example, you won't see strong carbonyl peak around $\pu{1700 cm-1}$ in FT-IR, which proves keto-form does not exists. It is 100% enol-form as phenol.

On the other hand, 4-pyridone is a different story. The dominance form, whether it is 4-pyridone or 4-hydroxypyridine, would be depend on which phase the compound is in. For example, the Ref.1 states that:

> In the gas phase, there is a preference of the hydroxy form in both 2- and 4-hydroxypyridine, while in a nonpolar solvents such as cyclohexane and chloroform, the two tautomers exist in comparable amounts. However, the two equilibria are shifted entirely to the right in favor of the *oxo*-form, 2- and 4-pyridone, respectively in polar solvents as well as in the crystalline state.

Thus, it is safe to say, it is only in the gas phase, 4-hydroxypyridine dominate. However, in liquid phases, both form exist where predominance is depending on the solvent. In solid phase, 4-pyridone dominate. Since, both phenol and 4-pyridone are solid at ambient conditions, phenol has more enol form than 4-pyridone, which exist in keto-form as a solid.

Note that a public database set like [Tautobase](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035), implemented in [DataWarrior](http://openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html), may be used to train yourself, too.

**Reference:**

1. Jiali Gao, Lei Shao, "Polarization Effects on the Tautomeric Equilibria of 2- and 4-Hydroxypyridine in Aqueous and Organic Solution," *J. Phys. Chem.* **1994**, *98(51)*, 13772–13779 (https://doi.org/10.1021/j100102a051).
2. Oya Wahl, Thomas Sander, "Tautobase: An Open Tautomer Database", *Chem. Inf. Model.* **2020**, *60*, 1085–1089 ([doi 10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035)).