# Is a tautomer's stability compared with refernce to its initial compund

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, molecular-structure, molecules, tautomer

Considering the following example while comparing the enolic content in the product, am I supposed to compare its stability with reference to its initial state or am I supposed to compare it between the final products obtained?

[image: Supposed question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given are keto form of keto-enol tautomerism of reference compounds. Answers are given according to the percentages of enol forms. Your duty is to find which enol form is dominant.

In cyclohexa-2,5-dienone, the enol form (phenol) dominate 100% in solid or in solutions, regardless of the solvent because of the aromaticity (100% B).

In the case of pyridones, however, the dominance form of the compound depends on which phase it is in. For instance, Ref.1 states that:

> In the gas phase, there is a preference of the hydroxy form in both 2- and 4-hydroxypyridine, while in a nonpolar solvents such as cyclohexane and chloroform, the two tautomers exist in comparable amounts. However, the two equilibria are shifted entirely to the right in favor of the *oxo*-form, 2- and 4-pyridone, respectively in polar solvents as well as in the crystalline state.

In general, pyridones' (e.g., 4-pyridone) predominance strongly over their tautomeric hydroxy forms (e.g., 4-hydroxypyridine) can be rationalized by considering the mesomerism of the alternative forms. The charge-separated form of 4-pyridone (far left; negative charge on more negative oxygen), being aromatic, is greatly preferred over the nonaromatic, charge-separated form of 4-hydroxypyridine (far right; negative charge on relatively more positive nitrogen).

[image: Pyridone-hydroxypyridine]

Thus, it is safe to say %B > %A and hence you have the correct answer.

**Note:** There are compilations about this type of keto-enol tautomerism. The freely available [Tautobase](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035) for example is provided as searchable database in [DataWarrior](http://openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html). Also read answers in [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125617/stability-of-4-pyridone-vs-4-pyridinol/126146#126146).

**References:**

1. Jiali Gao, Lei Shao, "Polarization Effects on the Tautomeric Equilibria of 2- and 4-Hydroxypyridine in Aqueous and Organic Solution," *J. Phys. Chem.* **1994**, *98(51)*, 13772–13779 (https://doi.org/10.1021/j100102a051).
2. Oya Wahl, Thomas Sander, "Tautobase: An Open Tautomer Database", *Chem. Inf. Model.* **2020**, *60*, 1085–1089 ([doi 10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035)).